# Displaying success/failure message on the form using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am creating a application using dojo 1.8.

I have a form with buttons to perform some action. Once the action is done, I get the status of the backend process execution. Currently I am using alert boxes to intimate user about the status. I know, it is very old fashioned. So what I am trying is: If the status is "success" then I will display a message (in green text) on the top of the form else the error message (in red).

For that in HTML file, I created two DIVs

```
<div id="successNotification" data-dojo-attach-point="successNotification"></div>
<div id="failureNotification" data-dojo-attach-point="failureNotification"></div>
```

and in the postCreate method, in requestCompleteCallback method of request.invokePluginService, I am trying to set the innerHTML of the DIV tag.
But below code always results in "successNotification is undefined" error.

```
if (ifSuccess == 'true' || ifSuccess )
{
    var successNotification = dijit.byId("successNotification");
}
```

In the same block I have used dijit.byId("some other component") and that works fine.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dijit.byId` is for retrieving Dijits, You should be using the **"dojo/dom"** module i.e `dom.byId` call instead to retrieve the DOM. see [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom.html) for details

Comment: If I use dom.byId, the value always comes as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm noticing several things here. First of all, your `if` code does not look valid (there's a `'` after `true`).

Then, if you're creating custom widgets you should not retrieve widgets or DOM nodes by their ID, which means you should **not** use either:

- `dijit.byId()`
- `dojo.byId()`
- `dojo/dom::byId()`
- `dijit/registry::byId()`

The correct way is by using the attach points you created by using the `data-dojo-attach-point` attribute. When you inherit from the `dijit/_TemplateMixin` mixin, you can simply use: `this.successNotification` and if you inherit from `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` as well, then you can use the same syntax to retrieve widget instances.

In your case it would be:

```
if (ifSuccess) {
  var successNotification = this.successNotification;
}
```

Comment: Missing quote(') was a typo error. The solution worked with a bit of change. As I had to access the element in the callback method, I could not access it directly with "this" object. so I had to store the reference of "this" object in a variable and then access the element using that variable.